# Working Example for Mahalanobis Distance Measure

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I need to measure the distance between two n-diensional vectors. It seems that Mahalanobis Distance is a good choise here so i want to give it a try.

My Code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial.distance.mahalanobis

x = [19, 8, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 18, 0, 1673, 9, 218]
y = [17, 6, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 8, 0, 984, 9, 30]
scipy.spatial.distance.mahalanobis(x,y,np.linalg.inv(np.cov(x,y)))
```

But I get this error message:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.pyc in mahalanobis(u, v, VI)
    498     v = np.asarray(v, order='c')
    499     VI = np.asarray(VI, order='c')
--> 500     return np.sqrt(np.dot(np.dot((u-v),VI),(u-v).T).sum())
    501 
    502 def chebyshev(u, v):

ValueError: matrices are not aligned
```

The Scipy Doc says, that `VI` is the inverse of the covariance matrix, and i think `np.cov` is the covariance matrix and `np.linalg.inv` is the inverse of a matrix...

But I see what is the problem here (matrices are not aligned): The Matrix VI has the wrong dimension (2x2 and not 13x13).
So possible solution is to do this:

```
VI = np.linalg.inv(np.cov(np.vstack((x,y)).T))
```

but unfortuanly the det of `np.cov(np.vstack((x,y)).T)` is 0, which means that a inverse matrix does not exsists.

so how can i use mahalanobis distance measure when i even cant compute the covariance matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a sample set with which to calculate a covariance. You probably just want the Euclidean distance here (`np.linalg.norm(x-y)`). What is the bigger picture in what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I currently use euclidian distance aka sum of squared differences. but i want to compare the results to other distance measures, to see what fits best into my program.

Comment: Sure, that's fine. Some distance measures (Euclidean (ssd is square of Euclidean), L1 norm, etc) you can use on two arbitrary vectors but the Mahalabonis distance is derived statistically and needs to learn the covariance matrix from a set of datapoints. The Euclidean distance can be seen as a special case of the Mahalabonis distance when you are not making or cannot make (i.e. in the absence of data) any assumptions about the distributions x and y may come from. You could just use an arbitrary spd matrix but that's not going to be meaningful.

Comment: okay, so better approach: find distances between all my datapoints first with euclidian distance, then cluster via some algorithm e.g. adjacency matrix based, now i have clusters and can decide with mahalanobis if a new datapoint belongs to any of the clusters?

Comment: It's impossible for me to say what the right approach is without a bigger picture of what you are doing.

Comment: [Multivariate Distances: Mahalanobis vs. Euclidean](https://waterprogramming.wordpress.com/2018/07/23/multivariate-distances-mahalanobis-vs-euclidean/)

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that Mahalanobis Distance is right for you application? According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) you need a set of points to generate the covariance matrix, not just two vectors. Then you can compute distances of vectors from the set's center.

Comment: As i read wp i see this: In order to use the Mahalanobis distance to classify a test point as belonging to one of N classes, one first estimates the covariance matrix of each class, usually based on samples known to belong to each class. Then, given a test sample, one computes the Mahalanobis distance to each class, and classifies the test point as belonging to that class for which the Mahalanobis distance is minimal.

so the problem is i need more vectors to compare with? So lets say i have them like x = [a,b, ..., n]; a = [0, ..., z]; then it will work?